# Задание для стажёров по Linux (ext4 metadata)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, ext4, initramfs

Специфика задачи такая: сломать метадату в файловой системе **ext4** и дать на восстановление стажёрам из под **initramfs**, что бы проверить их навыки.

Какие интересные способы для поломки и восстановления вы знаете?

> P.S процесс восcтановления должен быть не сложным и однозначным

Comment: Годная легенда.

Comment: Блин, наши стажёры ни разу винду не ставили, а тут - ext4. Аж завидно.